# What is maximum allowed length of iOS BundleId?

Tags: ios, bundle-identifier

I am trying to come up with regex to validate iOS app's bundle id. This [link](https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/deve21d0239c) was quite helpful. However I also need to validate length of supplied bundleid as well as length of strings between dots (here I am assuming there would be such restrictions from Apple) . For example, in bundle id 'com.company.project' I need to ensure 'company', 'project' etc are also within in allowed limit. I tried finding any apple docs that talks about maximum allowed bundle id but I couldn't. Is it like any length is allowed? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Max length of bundle id is 155 characters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Apparently 155 characters.

Checked in Apple Developer Account as seen below:

[image: BundleID]

Also, it could be one long character set without .'s

Answer (score 3):

From inspecting the HTML of the create App ID page on May 14, 2018, here are the constraints including a regular expression to validate the bundle identifier:

**Name**

- Maximum Length: 50
- Pattern: `^[0-9A-Za-z\d\s]+$`

**Bundle Identifier**

- Maximum Length: 155
- Pattern: `^[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]+$`

---

The original question was a regular expression to validate bundle identifiers, you could use this to do that:

```
^[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]{1,155}$
```

Comment: I think the regex should be `^[A-Za-z0-9\.\-]{1,155}$` - no + sign. + means "1 or more".